# JQuery - I can't clone my form events

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clone my form events but i cant, i created a script for tags, and they are working like that:

[image: print 1]

And i created a script to duplicate my form, i'm using JQuery clone(), and when i click at the duplicate link, it duplicates my form but not the events, resuming, the script that i created to write the tags only works for the first form, it doesn't work for the cloned forms

[image: Print 2]

Here my tags text fields

```
<label>Tags<a class="required_field">*</a></label>
<div id="wrapbox">
<div id="box">
<span id="checktags"></span>
<input type="text" class="to-be-clicked" id="tags"  maxlength="230">
</div>
</div>
```

The code for the scripts, i created an hidden textbox inside the script

```
   $('#tags').keypress(function(e) { //Check if space was clicked, and create a new tag
       if(e.which == 32) {
           var tx = $('#tags').val();
           if (tx) {
            $(this).val('').parent().before('<li class="tags"><span><input type="hidden" value="'+tx+'" name="tags[]" />'+tx+'</span><a style="cursor:pointer;" id="close">[x]</a></li>');
               closer();
           }
       }
   });
```

And my clone() function

```
$(function(){

    var template = $('#jb').clone();


    var offersCount = 1;

    window.addoffer = function(){

        offersCount++;

        var offer = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){

            var newId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length-1) + offersCount;


            this.name = this.id = newId; // update id and name (assume the same)

        }).end()
        .attr('id', 'att' + offersCount)
        .prependTo('#jb');
    }
    $('.add').click(addoffer);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `withDataAndEvents` arguement to `true` in your [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to clone the events as well: `.clone(true);`

As mentioned on the docs, this argument is by default `false` and is:

> "A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along
>   with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as
>   well."

Comment: @user3429726 Could you provide a jsFiddle showing it not working? btw, ID's need to be unique.